# Push notifcation custom sound stopped working

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have live app in app store which uses firebase fcm to send push notification using firebase cloud function. On arrival of push notification app plays custom sound provided in main bundle of xcode. But since last 24 hours app not playing custom sound for push notification on ios devices but its playing default iphone notfcation sound. On android devices its playing custom sound.i did not change sound file nor i update any code. The app is live in app store since months and suddenly stopped playing custom sound.
Velow is the code of my payload. Waiting for your help.

const payload = {

```
      notification: {

          title: 'New Orderد',
          body: 'New Order in '+storename,
          badge: '1',
          sound: 'mergedrequest.mp3',
          android_channel_id: 'driverrequestsoundchannelid'

      }
```

Comment: Have you updated your device os version?

Comment: no, its not playing custom sound on all ios devices

Comment: if i send fcm through postman then its playing custom sound on all ios devices

Comment: I have the same problem, custom sound was working, now not working! Is there any solution?

Comment: i think this is the fcm legacy api issue. i contacted firebase support. lets see what they reply.

Comment: thank you Request Logistic, I am waiting for you

Comment: They replied me with this message : I think the issue might be due to Admin SDK Messaging version you're using. The Admin SDK messaging now uses the HTTP v1 API which has a better multi-platform targeting options. I'd recommend to update to latest version available, and update your implementation code in sending messages. You can check our reference documentation on how to properly set the notification fields. Take note that you'll also need to update the authorization of send request. You can check our migration guide for more information.

Comment: okay, thank you,,,

Comment: If you fixed the issue kindly share the solution with me

Comment: Having the same issue with my live iOS app, started yesterday Aug 12.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find an easy solution. does the application need to be updated? SDK update?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I had custom sound in my notification. I did not change anything, but suddenly today the custom sound was replaced with the default one. Any solutions yet?

Comment: I think we have to update node js http legacy fcm api

Comment: Having the same issue with my live iOS app.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Firebase customer support:

> Just to set expectations, this issue was just recently identified as a
> bug with our Legacy API that’s not properly handling the custom sound
> for iOS. Our engineering team has identified the fix for this issue,
> and we couldn’t provide a definite timeline at the moment for the
> release in our production. For now, you might consider using our HTTP
> v1 API to send your messages.

Comment: They Fixed the bug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and migrating to HTTP v1 API worked for me

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: What steps did you take? I looked at the documentation, and it is extremely confusing. Can you post sample code that you used that worked? Perhaps post the before code and the after code?